# array changing values for a strange reason

Tags: javascript, arrays

Given the code below:

```
function createJson() {
var varry = new Array();
varry = x;
for (i=0 ; i < arry.length ; i++) { 
    if (arry[i]["questionVisibility"] == "1"){
        if (arry[i]["questionType"] != 3) {
            varry[i][1] = document.getElementById('te'+arry[i]["id"]+'et').value;
        } else {
            e = document.getElementsByName("te"+arry[i]["id"]+"et")[0];
            p = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
            varry[i][1] = p.text;
        }
    }
}

console.log(x);
console.log(varry);
```

Where X is an array that has been created like this(inside a different function):

```
x = document.getElementById("jsonData").value;
x = JSON.parse(x);
x = x[0];
x = x.data;
x = JSON.parse(x);
```

Can anyone explain me why when i call the createJson() function, the x array is changed? (x is already created when the createJson() is called)
Thanks in advance!

Comment: In the first 4 lines alone, there are 2 undefined variables

Comment: you didn't do a deepcopy, just pointed to x. for a detailed explanaion : 
https://medium.com/@tkssharma/objects-in-javascript-object-assign-deep-copy-64106c9aefab

Comment: when you call `varry = x` it's not copying data from 'x' to 'varry'. 'varry' is referring x (like pointers). if you want to create a copy, try this `varry = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( x ) )`

Comment: @DananjayaAriyasena thanks a lot, that worked!

Comment: Happy to hear that ... You are welcome :D

Answer (score 3):

it's because of line

```
varry = x;
```

assigning an array to variable creates kind of reference of original value so when you modify varry it also modifies x

if you want to get a copy of `x` into `varry` without reference use 
`array.slice()` like this:

`varry = x.slice();`

this will insert values from x into varry without creating 'reference' to original array

Comment: long way : `varry = JSON.parse( JSON.stringify( x ) )`

Comment: tried the x.slice(), i dont know why it didnt work. but @DananjayaAriyasena ' s way did work

Comment: @user3013562 `slice` creates shallow copy, so if your array contains objects, copy of array contains references to the same objects that original array